# remove whitespace between characters and words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to remove whitespaces between two words or more and two characters and more if exist.

Example :

```
text = " hello w    orld "
or
text = " h el lo       w    or  ld "
```

And I want to be like this :

```
text = "hello world"
```

NOT `"helloworld"` !!

is that possible ?

Comment: Not actually, this is more on natural language parser..

Comment: this is possible but the answer would be **too-broad** because it is not a simple problem that can be answered without a lot of code and explanation of natural language processing theory and algorithms.

Comment: How would Python know if `al bi ca` is `albi ca` or `al bica` or `albica` or simply `al bi ca`?

Comment: requests for recommendations is **off-topic** as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope it is not possible, because python can't assume what a word is, except you use natural language parsing algorithm,I personally don't think you'd want to dig that deep, but if you do then it's a cool area to explore
 :)